# Selenium Cannot Detect Color inside SAP Table

Tags: java, selenium, colors, background-color

I have a table with color that represent Working day and also Holiday or Public Holiday. Currently i need my robot to ignore Public Holiday and Holiday in order for me to get this done is to find the color for the header and robot can notify which field to insert and which to avoid. But currently the robot cannot give me the RGB color even though i have try the code and some solution inside stackoverflow.

sample table header that contain different color
[image]

```
<div id="__cell1" class="ZZBlockLayoutCell sapUiBlockHorizontalCell sapUiBlockLayoutCell sapUiBlockLayoutEvenCell" style="-webkit-flex:1;-ms-flex:1;flex:1" data-sap-ui="__cell1">
<div class="sapUiBlockCellContent " aria-labelledby="__cell1-Title">
<div id="__xmlview1--ZZDay1" class="sapMFlexBox sapMFlexBoxAlignContentStretch sapMFlexBoxAlignItemsStretch sapMFlexBoxBGTransparent sapMFlexBoxJustifyStart sapMFlexBoxWrapNoWrap sapMVBox ZZCalendarDateType01" style="height:100%" data-sap-ui="__xmlview1--ZZDay1">
<div id="__data278" class="sapMFlexBoxBGTransparent sapMFlexItem sapMFlexItemAlignAuto" style="order:0;flex-grow:0;flex-shrink:1;flex-basis:auto;min-height:auto;min-width:auto">
<div id="__data279" class="sapMFlexBoxBGTransparent sapMFlexItem sapMFlexItemAlignAuto" style="order:0;flex-grow:0;flex-shrink:1;flex-basis:auto;min-height:auto;min-width:auto">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

i have search inside stackoverflow and most of the answer give me the same method but i still cannot get the color of it

after i try to run this code the result from the table is as below

```
for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
WebElement ColorMonToSun = driver.findElement(By.id("__cell"+i));   
System.out.println(ColorMonToSun.getCssValue("background-color"));              
}
```

Result

```
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)


for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
WebElement ColorMonToSun = driver.findElement(By.id("__xmlview1--ZZDay"+i));    
System.out.println(ColorMonToSun.getCssValue("background-color"));              
}
```

Result

```
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Does SAP webpage have some different method to get the color? any solution for this will be great help thanks!

Comment: can u share HTML of table and any css classes associated ?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution to this issues, it need to have some small delay in order for Selenium to detect its color i have try this code and it manage to find the color, if no delay selenium will not be able to detect the color.

Main Class

```
for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {

                //Click Related Day
                sleep(1000);
                WebElement ColorMonToSun = driver.findElement(By.id("__xmlview1--ZZDay"+i));
                sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(ColorMonToSun.getCssValue("background-color"));
            }
```

Configuration Class

```
public static void sleep(long duration) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(duration);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Result

```
rgba(252, 234, 234, 1)
rgba(252, 234, 234, 1)
rgba(252, 234, 234, 1)
rgba(252, 234, 234, 1)
rgba(252, 234, 234, 1)
rgba(229, 229, 229, 1)
rgba(229, 229, 229, 1)
```